# Stack created in python using switch statement

Tags: python, switch-statement, stack

I created a stack program using switch but it seems it is not working properly. It keeps on iterating push method. It is not even quitting the program.

```
global a
a=[]
def push():
    push_no=int(input("Enter number you want to push"))
    a.append(push_no)

def pop():
    poped_item=a.pop()
    print("Poped item {}".format(poped_item))


def display():
    print(a)  

def numbers_to_strings(a1): 
    switcher = { 
        1: push(), 
        2: pop(), 
        3: display(),
        4: quit()
    } 
    return switcher.get(a1, "nothing")


# Driver program 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    while True:
        a1=int(input("ENTER WHICH OPERATION YOU WANT OT PERFORM 1-Push, 2-POP, 3-Display 4-quit"))
        numbers_to_strings(a1)
```

Comment: *python doesn't have a switch statement*

Answer (score 5):

In your `numbers_to_strings` definition, you have already evaluated the functions in your dictionary.   Try:

```
def numbers_to_strings(a1): 
    switcher = { 
        1: push, 
        2: pop, 
        3: display,
        4: quit
    } 
    return switcher.get(a1, "nothing")()  # get the function object, then evalutate
```